How to visualize wide plots with a common scroll bar, and "group" them with frozen blocks on the left?
I have a Shiny MWE like the one below, where I show some plots (passed from other tabs in the app).
I am able to accomplish this:
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


test_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
      plotOutput(outputId = ns("plot1"), height=100, width=1500),
      plotOutput(outputId = ns("plot2"), height=100, width=1500),
      plotOutput(outputId = ns("plot3"), height=100, width=1200),
      plotOutput(outputId = ns("plot4"), height=100, width=1200)
  )
}


test_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = drat)) +
      geom_point()
    })
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = qsec)) +
      geom_point()
    })
    output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = drat)) +
      geom_point()
    })
    output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = qsec)) +
      geom_point()
    })
  })
}

demoApp <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    test_ui("demo")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    test_server("demo")
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)  
}

demoApp()

which shows the plots like this:

What I would like though, is to accomplish something more similar to this:

where I have frozen (non-scrollable) blocks on the left with the plots "names" and "groups", and a common scroll bar for the x-axis of each of the groups.
Is this even possible? Can it be done in a simple way? I am not sure how to get started.

bslib easily lets you do this, with collapsible sidebars if you want: https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/articles/sidebars/index.html
library(bslib)

demoApp <- function() {
  ui <- page_fillable(
    layout_sidebar(
      sidebar = sidebar(
        # any content separate from the demo
      ),
      card(test_ui("demo"))
    ),
    layout_sidebar(
      sidebar = sidebar(
        # any content separate from the demo2
      ),
      card(test_ui("demo2"))
    )
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    test_server("demo")
    test_server("demo2")
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)  
}

edit: for fixed sidebars, you can switch out for page_fixed and use divs to make the containers
  ui <- page_fixed(
    layout_sidebar(
      sidebar = sidebar(
        fixedRow(
          column(width = 6,
               div(h1("col1"), style = "background-color: red; height: 500px; border:solid;")),
          column(width = 6, 
               div(h1("col2a"), style = "background-color: blue; height: 250px; border:solid;"),
               div(h1("col2b"), style = "background-color: green; height: 250px; border:solid;"))
      )),
      card(test_ui("demo"))
    ))


I already managed the scroll using `box(), but how about the color blocks... any idea?

edited my answer: you can add divs to create the blocks and adjust how you like within the style.
